# How to obtain AssetManager without reference to Context?

Tags: android, android-context

I have a class that needs to obtain a reference to it's application's `AssetManager`.  This class does not extend any sort of android UI class, so it doesn't have a `getContext()` method, or anything similar.  Is there some sort of static `Context.getCurrentApplicationContext()` type of method?

To clarify: my class is intended to be used like a library, for other applications. It has no associated `AndroidManifest.xml` or control over the context which is calling it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Create a subclass of [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), for instance `public class App extends Application {`
2. Set the `android:name` attribute of your `<application>` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to point to your new class, e.g. `android:name=".App"`
3. In the `onCreate()` method of your app instance, save your context (e.g. `this`) to a static field named `app` and create a static method that returns this field, e.g. `getApp()`:

This is how it should look:

```
public class App extends Application{

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Now you can use: `App.getContext()` whenever you want to get a context, and then `getAssetManager()` (or `App.getContext().getAssetManager()`).

Comment: To clarify, my class is intended to be used like a library, for other applications.  It has no associated AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: In that case, create the asset manager in the application and pass it to the library (through a method or constructor).

Comment: Seeing as how I intend for the library to be used by other developers in their applications, I was hoping there would be an alternative to requiring them to manually set the asset manager.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure of the best answer to the OP question.  However, I do know that you have to be very careful when using a static context as suggested in [Android developer resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html):

> In the `onCreate()` method of your app instance, save your context (e.g. this) to a static field named app and create a static method that returns this field, e.g. `getApp()`:

Using static contexts can leak to leaked memory issues, especially if the static context is used for references to views.

Comment: This concern is moot for the app instance itself, which is what is being stored in mContext, in Cristian's answer. The app instance has the same lifetime as your app; there is nothing to "leak". **The concern does become important if access to UI is needed**; in that case an `Activity` would be passed in as context, and it is important to have the activity make another call to "unregister" itself, in onPause and onDestroy. See  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13994622/199364 for such a technique, when Activity context is needed. `static WeakReference<Context> mContext` might also be helpful.