# Problems accessing my strings.xml items… i got numbers and not the string value

Tags: android, string

i found this problem some time ago, but i solve it using this: getString(), or this: getResources().getString()

but now, for this case, it doesn't works, i think it's because i need to get the string values on a NON ANDROID ACTIVITY CLASS. I need the resource values on a remote connection class, that doesn't extends any kind of activity or service.

how i can acces to the variables from my strings.xml on this normal class?

this is the code where i get the error (it gets an integer, and not the string value)

```
String a =R.string.totalpermission;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at these two answers (are the same XD):

- [How to obtain AssetManager without reference to Context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410328/android-how-to-obtain-assetmanager-without-reference-to-context/4410349#4410349)
- [How can I get a resource content from a static context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391720/android-how-can-i-get-a-resources-object-from-a-static-context/4391811#4391811)

Just an advice: try to read some basic concepts... it seems you don't understand what the R class is and how to use it. Trust me, you waste less time studying than trying to figure out how things work.

Answer (score 3):

I'll add something to existing answers since I found it very useful.

To get your strings you have to use a Context. Your activity will work just great.

```
String string = getString(R.string.myString);
```

But if you have something more complex... for exemple

```
R.string.result -> "You %1$s %2$d cats"

String result = getString(R.string.result, killed ? "killed": "saved", count);
```

That would give you a result like that:
You saved 10 cats or You killed 2 cats... and so on. You can pass parameters and positional arguments in strings will get replaced by your arguments in getString.

Comment: IMPORTANT: You need to adapt to the new more explicit format as soon as possible (i.e. You %1$s %2$d cats"), or else it won't compile under Gingerbread anymore.

Comment: I added an edit, I wasn't sure the new way was backward compatible. I did a test and it seems to work fine in older version of android. Apparently its an old feature that is now enforced.

Answer (score 1):

All Android resources are referenced via a resource ID, like `R.string.totalpermission`. You can see those numbers in `R.java` (although there's no reason to ever do that).

In cases of strings, you can easily get those using `Context.getString`. Bonus: You can even pass optional arguments and add dynamic strings that way. You always have a context - how are you getting called? If you really don't have a context, you can create one for the package your resources are in.