# Get instance of current visible activity

Tags: android, android-activity

How do I get the instance of the currently visible activity in Android? I've read that I can get the ComponentName of the activity by using ActivityManager to get a list of tasks and messing with that, but that's a recipe for disaster.

Is there a way to get an instance of the topmost activity, or if the activity isn't mine and I can't access it, just null?

Comment: Please define "mine". An activity from an application you wrote, or an activity from the same application instance the accessor code is running from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411395/how-to-get-current-foreground-activity-context-in-android ?

Answer (score -2):

TO get instance of currently visible activity, get its context as:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
```

or

```
mContext = this;
```

now use it for this activity related tasks.

OR to get instance of another activity; keep a static ActivityClass instance somewhere else and use getter setter to get set this instance like:

```
public void setActivity(MyActivity activity) {
         myActivity = activity;
    }

    public MyActivity getMyActivity() {
        return myActivity;
    }
```