# FragmentManager from application context

Tags: android, android-context, fragmentmanager

Is there a way to get FragmentManager from application context? I want to use ImageLoader or BitmapFun to store some bitmaps that I download from server. Both class require a FragmentManager to use to retain the cache over configuration changes such as an orientation change. In my case I want to pre-download the images before I actually "need" them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to get FragmentManager from application context?

No, because fragments are part of an activity.

> In my case I want to pre-download the images before I actually "need" them.

Then use a different library, one that does not have a dependency upon fragments.

Comment: do you know such a library? These are the only two I was able to find.

Comment: @learner: There are a seemingly infinite number of image retrieval libraries for Android. I use Square's Picasso personally, though my cases usually involve obtaining and applying the image, with side caching, rather than ahead-of-time caching. I have not researched all of the libraries to know which, if any, support your use case -- sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

First you have to read this solution to get the "Current activity" of your application:

[How to get current foreground activity context in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411395/how-to-get-current-foreground-activity-context-in-android)

```
Activity activity = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).getCurrentActivity();    
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
```

Comment: getApplicationContext()).getCurrentActivity() does not work for me. 
There is no getCurrentActivity from the application context.

Comment: @davidmlee getCurrentActivity() is just a getter for your instance variable in the Application class called currentActivity

Comment: georgiecasey ic.  I like this idea of getting it from the application object.  Activities come and go, but the application is a singleton.