# How can AlarmBroadcastReceiver check if there is no Activity from specified package running

Tags: android

Currently, I have a stock market app. When the stock market app "quit", it will start `AlarmBroadcastReceiver`, to monitor the stock market in background.

This code would looks like this.

```
// Code from main activity.
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver.startAlarmBroadcastReceiver(this);
```

However, there's a tricky part here. It is extremely difficult to tell, when an app is "quit".

From end user perspective, "quit" really mean, when there is no `Activity` screen from the app package visible on screen.

`onPause` will be triggered in the following situations

- Back button pressed. - Should start `AlarmBroadcastReceiver`
- Home button pressed. - Should start `AlarmBroadcastReceiver`
- Launch another `Activity` (Like settings preference activity) from main `Activity`. - **I wish not. But it will start `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` with current code**

It is difficult to differentiate *Back button pressed* / *Home button pressed* with *Launch another `Activity` from main `Activity`*.

Using `isFinishing` wouldn't work for my case, as it only return true during *Back button pressed*, not *Home button pressed*

Hence, I decide to install the following logic, at the early of `AlarmBroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive`

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // If the current on screen activity, is *SAME* application package
        // as AlarmBroadcastReceiver. This mean our app is not "quit" yet.
        // We should return early without performing anything else.
```

However, I realize this is not an easy thing to do, as I can see from

[How to get current foreground activity context in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411395/how-to-get-current-foreground-activity-context-in-android)

- `ActivityManager`'s `getRunningTasks` is depreciated in Android 5.
- Or, according to answer of gezdy, you need to have "hacky" code to update a global static variable, in every Activities in your app.

The suggested solution doesn't really look much elegant, and maintainable to me.

I was wondering, is there any better workaround, for my case? So that I can prevent `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` from running its logic code, when other `Activity` within same package is still visible on screen.

Comment: apart from `onPause` there are other other "finishing" callbacks like `onStop` and `onDestroy`, try them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help to some extent. This is what I found while googling around.

1. You can register Activity Life Cycle with [registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks callback)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks%28android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks%29)
   , but introduced in **API Level 14.**
2. A blog written by [Steve Liles - Is my Android app currently foreground or background](http://steveliles.github.io/is_my_android_app_currently_foreground_or_background.html) using [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)

Comment: Pretty much useful. I apply the info from this answer, to another similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29786451/72437