# Reference to Current Activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Can some one help me get the reference to the current activity from the Myapp that extends Application. I'm trying to implement a simple shake feature that uses the [sesmic](https://github.com/square/seismic) library. Once the shake is detected I need to have the reference to the current activity so that I can save a screen shot of the current view. I need to access the current activity something like

```
enter public class MyApp extends Application {

public onSomeTriggerCallThisFunction() {
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
}}
```

Can someone help me with getCurrentActivity()

Comment: Go over this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411395/how-to-get-current-foreground-activity-context-in-android

Comment: That question and this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13994622/3162918

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For API level 14 :

They added new public function

```
public void registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks (Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks callback)
```

Implementing them in your application class can give access to current activity.

To [read about it's Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks))...

[An Example to get started with...](http://baroqueworksdev.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-use-activitylifecyclecallbacks.html)

Answer (score 2):

you should set currentActivity when you call each activity in onCreate or onResume activity method like that.
G is my Application class and currentActivity is my static field in G class

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    G.currentActivity = this;
}
```

Comment: Don't. Do. This. Ever.

Comment: See [Avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)