# Calling/Attaching MainAcitivty method to click of notification button

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-broadcastreceiver

Have been creating a custom notification, so far implemented it successfully getting the notification, however when i am trying to call a function/method from MainActivity using the button on the notification i created i get the below error :

```
System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

Below is the method defined by me inside the MainActivity that updates the notification UI and also stops the mediaplayer.

```
public void attachMediaActivity()
{
    //INITIALIZE THE CONTEXT
    context =this;

    notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    remoteViews=new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),R.layout.custom_notification);

    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notif_icon,R.drawable.stream_icon);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notif_title,"stopped");

    Intent button_intent= new Intent("button_clicked");
    button_intent.putExtra("id",notification_id);

    Intent notification_intent=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notification_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder =new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true);

    notificationManager.notify(notification_id,builder.build());

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

Broadcast listener attached to the button of notification that calls the above method from main activity.

```
   public class Button_listener extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        NotificationManager manager =(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(intent.getExtras().getInt("id"));
        Toast.makeText(context, "GENERATED BY NOTIFICATION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new MainActivity().attachMediaActivity();
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
01-24 11:52:29.010 13062-13062/com.amplitude.tron.samplemediaplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.amplitude.tron.samplemediaplayer, PID: 13062
                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.amplitude.tron.samplemediaplayer.Button_listener: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2750)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5288)
                                                                                          at com.amplitude.tron.samplemediaplayer.MainActivity.attachMediaActivity(MainActivity.java:159)
                                                                                          at com.amplitude.tron.samplemediaplayer.Button_listener.onReceive(Button_listener.java:21)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2743)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1433) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5525) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

What i have implemeted so far : 
[image: NOTIFICATION SNAPSHOT]

where am i going wrong .. also prior to calling notification manager i have been getting getPackageName() as NULL
Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot instantiate an `Activity` with `new` and have it work correctly.

Comment: @MikeM. yes i know even if it is calling the MainActivity its onCreate is not getting called .. thats why i posted this query for a solution / advise

Comment: `OnCreate` won't get called if you try to instantiate it with a `new`

Comment: @fluffyBatman so should i create class variable for it and then call the method ?

Answer (score 0):

```
new MainActivity().attachMediaActivity();
```

Problem lies here. Contrary of normal way, creating an instance of Activity with a `new` tag won't let you go through with its lifecycle that it supposed to.

You can launch your Activity by setting up a bundle, pass it with `Intent`, initiate a  `startActivity` and finally check the bundle value in Activity and invoke the `attachMediaActivity` method. Or else, if you want, you can get a hold of your current Activity instance in [these ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411395/how-to-get-current-foreground-activity-context-in-android) and call the method.

Comment: hi i have never used intents .. although i may be this make sense ?
intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); then where to next !?
the context and intent is the onReceive parameters!

Comment: Head over to this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html and go through the content. You'll get the idea on how to begin an Activity through Intent with bundle.

Comment: Hi fluffyBatman i have managed to get the notification working however i have a problem on the notification button click, the activity get recreated on top of the old activity! and if i try to change the launchmode to single the above UI changes doesnt happen, please help

Answer (score 0):

The error that you got clearly says, System services not available to Activities before onCreate().
That is, You can not use `NotificationManager` from an `Activity` without calling `startActivity(Intent)`.

What you can do is, start the activity with intent+ extras to call the method inside the MainActivity. OR you can use the CallBack method using Interfaces.

**Update**
Declare Intent as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("attachMedia",true); // Extra info
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

And now, inside the MainActivity onCreate(), (after all initialization)

```
boolean attachMedia = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("attachMedia",false);
if (attachMedia) {
attachMediaActivity();
}
```

Comment: Hi Nizam this is what i have done so far :
        intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: How do i make a call to Main Activity function ?? 
PS : i am new to INTENTS

Comment: addExtra is not recognized !

Comment: Sorry, Typo. Use putExtra()

Comment: Hi Nizam its working however it is creating a new notification instead of updating the old one also given that i am using the same notification id, any thoughts on that ?

Comment: From where, you are triggering the first notification? Is it Ongoing(true)?

Comment: Yes ongoing is true... i am creating the notification using onClickListener of button in the main activity

Comment: Hi nizam i kind of got it working but, there is two activity getting created when i click on notif button, and when i change the launch mode to single then the above ui changes dont work... please help