# How can i get list of all running activities and select any activity from pause to start state?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app and i want to get all the running activities list in the listview and select any activity from the list and that activity will go to pause to start state.

How is this possible. by using activities or if you have any other suggestion will also be consider.

i want to save instance and start activity from where it was left by selecting it from the listview.

Comment: You cant have more than one activity running at once - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411395/how-to-get-current-foreground-activity-context-in-android), it may help you

Comment: so what i use to code like this, for making tabs like a browser. can i make tabs using fragments or something else.@TamirAbutbul

Comment: Yes sure, check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral) and also [this](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save instance of the activity and then start that instance