# How to discover what Activity is on the foreground in Android app?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I need to implement the logic - If user on chat activity then I don't need to show push notification with new message. So I need to know what activity is on the screen. For this purpose I found this answer [How to get current foreground activity context in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411395/how-to-get-current-foreground-activity-context-in-android) But I don't understand how to use

```
public void registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks (Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks callback)
```

Can some one give me a full example how to discover what activity is on screen?

Comment: Sample on [this git repo](https://github.com/kiranboghra/app-foreground-background-listen) may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement `onActivityPaused` and `onActivityResumed()`

```
    public class YourApplication extends Application implements
    Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    public static boolean isChatVisible=false;   

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity p0, Bundle p1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity p0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity p0) {

         isChatVisible=p0 instanceof ChatActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity p0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity p0) {

    }

}
```

Before building the notification just check `YourApplication.isChatVisible()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic structure of what you need to do:

```
public class AmpApplication extends Application implements
    Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        if(activity instanceof ChatActivity) {
            // chat activity is in foreground
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        // do nothing
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your push notifications are received by service class in your app (and I guess you are interested in foreground activity from your app, i.e. the same code base).

Maybe there are more elegant and smarter solutions, but you can also do a bit crude one like this:

Add flag (`static boolean doNotCreateNotification = false;` is enough for the simple scenario of chat activity prohibiting notifications) to `MyApplication extends Application` class (add new one, if you don't have yet one in your project, make sure you reconfigure the project correctly to use custom `Application` class).

Now this static flag will be pretty much "global" for all the code which is running from your app, including all activities and/or background service processing notifications.

The `Activity` life cycle guarantees that `onResume` is called when activity becomes foreground+active one, and `onPause` when the activity is leaving such state. So you can update the global flag in these to true/false in the `onResume/onPause` methods.

Then in the service processing received notification you can check if the flag is set to `true` and just discard the notification data without creating badge in the OS.

Comment: "Rajasekaran M" answer is in principle doing the same thing, but feels a bit less hack-ish, as you are accessing the `Application` instance through life-cycle callback interface, which is designed for this kind of stuff, while direct access of static fields in custom `Application` is a bit ugly thing (for example makes Unit testing lot more difficult).