# Checking which activity is currently running from class which is not an activity/fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-context

I am looking for solution how to check which activity is currently running in class which is not an activity/fragment. In constructor I have an applicationContext. Is there a way to use it? Any other ideas?

Greetings

Comment: You can do this with help of `lifeCycle`. Check more [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle)

Comment: There may be 0, 1, or several activities "currently running".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411395/how-to-get-current-foreground-activity-context-in-android