# getAssets().open doesn't open my .csv file

Tags: java, android, csv, opencsv

I want to assignt my CSVreader from the openCSV api to a CSV file, but it can't find it, as I get an "cannot resolve symbol" error.

code:

```
 CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(getAssets().open(testCSV.csv));
```

I'm using Android Studio, and the file is located under src/main/assets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably means testCSV.csv needs to be a string so "testCSV.csv" with the quotes

Comment: oh god, yes, very stupid mistake. But i still get an error, now it's an IO.Exception

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `getAssets().open("myFile")` on your current context. so give your context to the function, like this:

```
public void openFile(Context context){
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(context.getAssets().open("testCSV.csv"));
}
```

Comment: should i then be calling openFile(); in onCreate, becuase when i do that i get an error

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410328/how-to-obtain-assetmanager-without-reference-to-context and also have a read here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: in my Andoid manifest it says android:name cannot be assigned to app.